# Submit an array string from codename one to PHP using connection request

Tags: php, codenameone

Am fetching data from mysqlite to a string array which i want to submit to PHP then update a mysql table.
Any easy way out, because doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Let's see that code, and what's wrong with it.  See Help.

Comment: sqlite != mysql. Which portion doesn't work? Fetching the data? Submitting the data to PHP? Updating the result? What are you doing specifically?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I want to update data to a MySql db. Am able to fetch the data from sqlite and convert in to a string array and use connection request to submit the array to php. Am unable to convert the submitted data to php array.

Comment: @WillBriggs Java code    
    request.setUrl(StateMachine.ApiUrl);
    request.setPost(true);
    request.addArgument("call", "4");
    request.addArgument("data", Arr);                                                                                   php code 
    $Data = isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : '';
    $DataArr = json_decode($Data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the network monitor tool to see that the Codename One code is sending out the right data as explained in the [IO section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html).

I notice your PHP code tries to decode JSON into an array whereas your Java code adds a POST array both of which have nothing in common. I don't really know PHP's equivalent for handling an array so I can't help you there. On the Codename One side you can just write the array as JSON by converting it to a JSON String.